# SRSS Reporting Services Migrar a otra instancia SQL

Tags: sql-server-2017, reporting, sql-server-2022

Quiero compartir el sgte problema.

Tengo instalado un SQL Server edición Developer 2017 en una laptop y he querido migrar su Reporting Serives cifrando la key y backupeando las bases de datos, todo ello lo he querido llevar a un SQL Server edición Developer 2022, de echo he podido hacerlo, restaurando las bases en el SQL 2022 y restaurando la Key del Reporting Services pero al abrir la url del porta web es donde no puedo ver el reporte, y me sale este error:

[image: imagen donde quiero migrar el reporting services]

no entiendo que indica el error, por ello si supieran como podría arreglaro les estaría muy agradecido.

Psdt: En mi laptop que tiene SQL 2017 si abre el reporte ya que allí tengo creado el reporte desde el visual studio y en la otra laptop donde está en SQL 2022 es donde sale el error.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.